# Update after a table field change

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-5

I have a problem with a old Delphi system, this system insert data into a SQL Server table.

After 10 years change a field of the table from 100 to 255 chars long.

The system select all the registris of the table, and put them on an other table after a transformation. That works fine.

The problems are when the system update a field.

That show me the error

> EDBEngineError with message 'Couldn't perform the edit because another user changed the record.

```
sConsulta:='SELECT * FROM cuentas WHERE (WALL= 2) AND (SEND_DATE = '01/01/1970')';
m_oQryLeg.Close;
m_oQryLeg.SQL.Clear;
m_oQryLeg.SQL.Add(sConsulta);
m_oQryLeg.Open;
m_oTblNov.Close;
m_oTblNov.TableName:='des_table';
m_oTblNov.Open;

with m_oTblNov do
begin
  while (not m_oQryLeg.EOF) do
  begin
    Insert;
    FieldbyName('COD_HOME').AsString:= m_oQryLeg.FieldByName('USR_HOME').AsString;
    (...)
    Post;

    m_oQryLeg.Edit;
    m_oQryLeg.FieldByName('SEND_DATE').AsDateTime:= Date; //<-- HERE THE ERROR
    m_oQryLeg.Post;

    m_oQryLeg.First;
    m_oQryLeg.MoveBy(i);
    inc(i);
  end;    
end;
m_oTblNov.Close;
m_oQryLeg.Close;
```

UpdateMode: upWhereAll

cuentas table:

- NUM_SOL      nvarchar    6   *PK
- WALL     tinyint     1
- SEND_DATE    smalldatetime   4
- OBS_CRED     nvarchar    255
- FLCC     real        4
- STREET       nvarchar    30

Comment: You should provide more information, maybe a a piece of code

Comment: Which update mode are you currently using?  And can you provide a list of columns and types in the cuentas table?  it's possible one of them is causing the error, the BDE has issues with certain floating point types.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to update a query you're using on a table you're editing at the same time, and it's not going to work.

Since you know you're going to insert every row from the query into `m_oTblNov`, why not just do it like this instead?

```
sConsultaSELECT :='SELECT * FROM cuentas';
sConsultaUPDATE := 'UPDATE cuentas SET Send_Date = :New_Date';
// Separate WHERE so you can use it twice. Note the leading space
// between the first ' and WHERE.
sWhere := ' WHERE (WALL = 2) and (SEND_DATE = ''01/01/1970'')';


m_oQryLeg.Close;
m_oQryLeg.SQL.Text := sConsulta + sWhere;
m_oQryLeg.Open;

m_oTblNov.Close;
m_oTblNov.TableName:='des_table';
m_oTblNov.Open;

with m_oTblNov do
begin
  while (not m_oQryLeg.EOF) do
  begin
    Insert;
    FieldbyName('COD_HOME').AsString:= m_oQryLeg.FieldByName('USR_HOME').AsString;
    (...)
    Post;

    // Don't run these any more. See below.
    // m_oQryLeg.Edit;
    // m_oQryLeg.FieldByName('SEND_DATE').AsDateTime:= Date; //<-- HERE THE ERROR
    // m_oQryLeg.Post;

    m_oQryLeg.First;
    m_oQryLeg.MoveBy(i);
    inc(i);
  end;    
end;
m_oTblNov.Close;
m_oQryLeg.Close;
m_oQryLeg.SQL.Text := sConsultaUPDATE + sWHERE;
m_oQryLeg.ParamByName('New_Date').AsDateTime := Date;
try
  m_oQryLeg.ExecSQL;
finally
  m_oQryLeg.Close;
end;
```

Comment: The problem with that solution if is some error happend before the execution of sConsultaUPDATE the system wouldn't update the dates.
Any way I'm resolve the problem doing that but is not the correct way, it should update the date field,field by field like work before change the table.

Comment: Then you should be wrapping all of this in a transaction, and rolling back if there is an error, or using two tables and a filter instead of a query and `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your object is trying to refresh the row from the database to make sure nothing has changed and more than likely the object truncated or rounded some value that is causing the refresh to return no rows.

This could be caused by either a float value being truncated or some other value being off.

if you don't/can't change that column to fix this issue I would advise changing to either upWhereChanged or upWhereKeyOnly.

Given that dates are treated as doubles in most windows databases, I would think that upWhereKeyOnly would be best.

EDIT:

After looking at your table, it may have to do with the fact you are using a single based smalldatetime.  Delphi treats all DateTime data as a double and the conversion back and forth may be causing small rounding issues.

Comment: I tried with upWhereChanged and upWhereKeyOnly nothing works
If you think is usefull, I could copy all the Object Inspector properties.

Comment: Can you script out the table?